# Lighthouse CLI authentication

Tags: authentication, lighthouse

I'm trying to perform audit using Lighthouse CLI (not tab in DevTools but [Node CLI tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse)). My app requires authentication.

Maybe somebody knows how to pass authentication in such a case?

I'm using command line like the following

```
lighthouse https://example.com:8100/some-path/ --budget-path=budget.json --output-path=report.html
```

Comment: any news on that one? doing similar thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below options with CLI

```
--extra-headers={auth cookies}
```

OR use debugging port with CLI that lighthouse can open pages on same browser instance where authentication is already done

```
--port=9222 //9222 is just an example
```